# Anywhere to buy raw historical tweets?

Tags: twitter

I see a few places, like gnip, where feeds start at 30k, and a bunch of places that sell analysis.  But is anyone still selling access to raw historical tweets? What I'm trying to get, I could have purchased from Topsy for $200 if they were still around.

Comment: What do you mean by historical? Twitter search now indexes all tweets - so you should be able to get them directly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  By "historical" I mean older than the 2-week limit on API searches.  (Up to two years back.)  The search now indexes them, you're right, but (a) there's no access via an API, so they'd have to be scraped, (b) are you aware of anyone who's managed to scrape it?  I'd be surprised if they don't detect and throttle/block scrapers. (c) I'm not confident the search is complete.  Through the API you have a choice between "raw data" and "those tweets twitter thinks you want to see," and what comes back on the search page feels like the latter.

Comment: Just to be clear - if anyone had a working scraper, I'd jump on it, but even if its feasible, since I haven't tried this before I'd spend a week just doing that.  I'd rather spend the money and buy them than devote a week to learning a whole new programming technique for a one-shot.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using the streaming API - grab tweets for a few weeks.

Comment: @Terence  Right.  But I'm not looking for just any tweets.  I need tweets in a specific time period going back about two years.   I did some more searching, and it looks like there are scrapers for user data, but not tweets.  At the bulletin boards for internet marketers (I had to take a shower after browsing there...) there were several topics complaining about the lack of a tweet-scraper.

Answer (score 0):

There were no services selling historical tweets other than as part of a "firehose" feed starting at $20,000/month.  I was able to scrape the tweets using the `rvest` package for R.